# Can't ssh into Apache server after changing file ownership?

Tags: apache, ssh, centos

I changed the owner of some of the folders on our Apache web server to my username so I could make edits, I changed them all back to the root. I was using `sudo chown username:group -R *`. Now no one can SSH in to the server. I have no idea what the problem could be. Changes I made:

- Misc web edits in `var/www/html`
- Created .htaccess file from [here](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess?ts=2) in `/var/www/html` (was trying to enable gzip)
- Changed the "AllowOverride" from "None" to "All" here (was trying to enable the .htaccess file) in `/etc/httpd/conf`:

#

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All
```

In order to do all of this I needed to change the owner of the folders to my username, which I did. Then I changed them back. Presto change-o, no one can log in. How did I screw up?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is ask someone to SSH in debug mode. You can turn debugging on with the `-v` flag. For example, `ssh -v user@hostname`.

The most likely cause for your troubles is you have auth set to public key only, and the permissions for the `.ssh` folder in each user's home directory on the server is incorrect. Verify:

- the .ssh directory permissions to be 700 (drwx------) on the server
- the public key (.pub file) to be 644 (-rw-r--r--)
- the private key (id_rsa) on the user's machine should be 600 (-rw-------)
- lastly, each user's home directory (on the server) should not be writeable by the group or others (at most 755 (drwxr-xr-x))

See [this](https://superuser.com/a/215506/94079) answer for more info.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the response. I went in with ssh -v and got this: `OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to conference.cpes.vt.edu [128.173.89.44] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/laurenshutt/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
(this repeats for awhile)`

Comment: Then: `debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to conference.cpes.vt.edu:22 as 'support2'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection reset by 128.173.89.44
`